# Show multiple navigation at a time in google maps - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am developing an android app where more than one user can connect like whatsapp along with their location.

For example,
I have connected with three friends called A, B, and C. I can able to get their location in latitude&longitude and showing those in the google map. I implemented that.

If I start moving I can see that my location also moving. I implemented this using GPS.

Here I also want to show the navigation of my friends if they started moving. (Multiple navigation at one time) How can I achieve this? Is this possible with Google Maps?

I searched for solutions in SO and google. Cant find. Help needed.

Comment: You should use `Marker`s. Read about them here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

Comment: yeah. by using markers only i am showing the latlong of the peoples. I want to navigate the marker while the person starts moving.

Comment: You would have to have your program somehow share the users current LatLng as retrieved from getLastLocation(): https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: getLastLocation() will get only my location right? I want to show my friend's location whenever they are moving.

Comment: Use push notification to receive friend locations from your app on the other peoples' devices.

Comment: Actually i am getting their locations from gcm using webservices and then fixing in the map.